# On the Puppe sequence for the cofibration induced by the inclusion of skeleta

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a finite CW complex and denote by $X_k$ the $k$-skeleton of $X$. We have the natural cofibration
$$
 X_k \to X \to C(i_k)
$$

where $i_k\colon X_k \to X$ is the inclusion. The Puppe sequence is now given as
$$
X_k \to X \to C(i_k) \to \Sigma X_k \to \Sigma X\to \dots.
$$
Now I have $C(i_k)$ homotopy equivalent to $X/X_k$. Is there a nice description of the map
$X/X_k \to \Sigma X_k$?

Comment: What do you mean by a "nice" description? It is the composite of $X/X_k\cong C(i_k)/C(X_k)\xleftarrow{\sim}C(i_k)→C(i_k)/X=ΣX_k$, so in order to have an explicit map you essentially need to find an inverse of the equivalence $C(i_k)→C(i_k)/C(X_k)$. You can get it from some kind of "tubular neighborhood" of $X_k$ in $X$, but I doubt there's anything more explicit

Comment: Thank you for this helpful comment. In case $X$ is a manifold, is it then possible to find an explicit map by using some tubular neighborhood?

Comment: If you have a neighborhood of $X_k$ that's homeomorphic to some vector bundle $p:E→X_k$, then put a metric on $E$ and the map $X/X_k→ΣX_k$ is given by the constant map outside of $E/X_k$ and $(e^{2\pi i |v|/(1+|v|)},pv)∊S^1\wedge X_k$ for $v$ in $E$.